# react component from parent array is not an actual array

Tags: c#, reactjs, asp.net-web-api

I'm trying to pass an array from axios get request, my backend server is written in C#.
This is the request:

```
// GET: api/<SettingsController>
        [HttpGet]
        public IActionResult Get()
        {
            try
            {
                return Ok(_repo.GetAccounts().ToList());
            }
            catch (Exception)
            {
                return BadRequest();
            }
        }
```

This is my parent component:

```
const SettingsPage = () => {
    const [allAccounts, setAllAccounts] = useState("");
    useEffect(() => {
        axios.get("https://localhost:9000/api/settings").then((response) => {
          setAllAccounts(response.data);
        });
      }, []);
    return (
                <Table type="הגדרות"  allAccounts = {allAccounts} selectAccount = {selectAccount}/>
    )
}

export default SettingsPage
```

That is my child component (which is also a parent to a different component):

```
const Table = (props) => {
    const [allAccounts, setAllAccounts] = useState([]);
    useEffect(()=>{
        setAllAccounts(props.allAccounts);
    },[])
    return (
                    {allAccounts.map((account) =>{
                        <TableRow account = {account} />
                    })}
    )
}

export default Table
```

And I bump into a runtime error:
`props.allAccounts.map is not a function TypeError: props.allAccounts.map is not a function`

Iv'e tried to use a different variable (var arr = []) and push each element seperatly, the type error is just "props.allAccounts.ForEach is not a function".
Iv'e also tried to use the allAccounts constant from the useState hook and the result is the same error.
It might be important also to acknowledge that the array in the console.log function is looking okey:

```
(2) [{…}, {…}]
0
: 
{id: 3, name: null, dateCreated: '2023-06-14T13:52:18.2417005', supervisorId: 1, supervisor: null, …}
1
: 
{id: 4, name: 'Wise-code', dateCreated: '2023-06-14T14:05:23.9261187', supervisorId: 2, supervisor: null, …}
length
: 
2
[[Prototype]]
: 
Array(0)
```

This is also the array i get from the response in postman.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are already passing allAccounts from SettingsPage component to the Table component as props. So you can access it in the Table component directly, without using useEffect.

```
const Table = ({allAccounts}) => {    
    return (
        {
            allAccounts.map((account) =>  <TableRow account={account} key={account.id} />)
        }
    )
}

export default Table;
```

Also you had better to initialize the state to empty array in SettingsPage so that it does'nt cause problem in the first render.

```
const [allAccounts, setAllAccounts] = useState([]);
```

Comment: Wanted to thank you, helped me a lot.